# Is there a way to use IOS API to get Mac os version of my App working?

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mac-catalyst, mapbox-ios

I am building iOS and MacOS app. Both share Swift code base. Seems like Mapbox does not support MacOS.

So currently I am using Mapbox GL JS as a web view.
What I found is if I use my styles in Mapbox Ios Preview App, navigations are super smooth and tiles load very fast. But in Safari or Chrome it is not.

I assume there is a difference between MapBox IOS API and Mapbox GL JS?
Do you know of any way to use IOS API to get Mac os version of my App working? Seems Catalyst is not supported as well. Maybe there is something in workings by Mapbox ?

It just smooth navigation is key for me. Any advice ?

Thank you so much for your time and advice, much appreciated it !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make something for both iOS and macOS, I suggest you consider  starting with an iOS SDK app, and have a roadmap where you let it run as "Designed on iPhone" on MacOS on Apple Silicon CPUs.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/running-your-ios-apps-in-macos#3655400

This is dependent on your platform priorities, and also assumes that the iOS version of Mapbox will continue working, but that is a very specific question you can answer.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem Mapbox iOS does not Support Mac Catalyst

Comment: Yeah, so you could still do iOS-only w/o catalyst, and run it on MacOS. Apple notes that some frameworks might not work, but this is technically a different scenario from Mac Catalyst, so you should ask them specifically.